# Cómo recorrer un rango de celdas y añadir valor a cada celda

Tags: excel, vba, macros

soy nuevo en Visual Basic y estoy aprendiendo poco a poco Macros de Excel.
Tengo una tabla donde posee 5 columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es super simple.
Necesito filtrar el `criterio de estilo y diseño`, con la finalidad de que el rango `("C5:F15")`, es decir el rango de valores, puedan sumar un valor de 100 cuando la celda posea el valor `Ej:Celda("D4") sería 500,00 + 100 = 600,000`. Es decir, las celdas vacías no se sumen.

La idea es hacerlo con Macros, pero recién estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: Hola ignacion, bienvenido a SO. Podrías mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora? Esto es tan sencillo como meter los datos en un array, recorrrer las filas para comprobar el criterio en la columna C, y luego recorrer las columnas D, E y F, y si son mayores que 0 y cumplen el cirterio, sumar 100.

Comment: @Damian la verdad, no tengo idea de como hacerlo. Empecé hace dos días esto y lo necesito hacer. ¿sería posible que me puedas ayudar con esto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo sencillo:

```
Sub suma_100()

    Dim rango As Range
    Dim celda As Range

    Set rango = Range("D4:F15")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each celda In rango

        If celda.Value > 0 And Cells(Celda.Row, "C") = "Estilo" Or celda.Value > 0 And Cells(Celda.Row, "C") = "Diseño" Then celda.Value = celda.Value + 100

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Lo que hago es definir un rango de datos, el que has puesto y luego evaluar cada una de las celdas de ese rango. Si la celda tiene valor le sumo 100.

Ojo que habría que añadir más cosas si quieres evitar errores porque alguien escriba texto, por ejemplo.

También podría hacerse cómo dice el compañero, metiendo los valores en un array, evaluando esos valores y sumando 100 y volcando de nuevo el array a la hoja con el resultado. 
Para un rango muy grande de datos esto último es mucho más eficiente.

P.D. El código lo he escrito para ejecutarlo en la propia hoja donde tienes los datos.

Comment: dogwall me funciona de maravilla, aunque está ejecutando todo el rango, y la idea era que funcione sólo cuando el criterio sea en estilo y diseño.

Comment: Te falta una condición dogwall. `If celda.Value > 0 And Cells(Celda.Row,  "C") = "Criterio" Or celda.Value > 0 And Cells(Celda.Row, "C") = "Diseño" Then` sería completo.

Comment: Cierto, no leí con detenimiento lo que necesitaba. Ya he editado mi respuesta con lo que sugieres.

Gracias.